# Aggregate rows by id comparing column values

Tags: mysql

I have the following table that groups users by their permissions

```
userIds     permissions
4,5,7,8     100,1600,500,501,502,400,401,1500,1501
```

The numbers in the permissions column are the sections ids.

Some of these sections may have other data associated which I retrieved and stored in another table.

```
sectionId   userId  resourceId
100     4   NULL
1600    4   NULL
500     4   NULL
501     4   NULL
502     4   NULL
400     4   NULL
401     4   1
1500    4   NULL
1501    4   NULL
100     5   NULL
1600    5   NULL
500     5   NULL
501     5   NULL
502     5   NULL
400     5   NULL
401     5   1,2
1500    5   NULL
1501    5   NULL
100     7   NULL
1600    7   NULL
500     7   NULL
501     7   NULL
502     7   NULL
400     7   NULL
401     7   2
1500    7   NULL
1501    7   NULL
100     8   NULL
1600    8   NULL
500     8   NULL
501     8   NULL
502     8   NULL
400     8   NULL
401     8   1
1500    8   NULL
1501    8   NULL
```

My goal is to compare, for each user in the userIds column of the first table (splitted by comma), every row of the second table in order to check if each user has the same resourceId value for that specific sectionId.

If one or more users have the same resourceId value for each section I want to keep them group together, otherwise they need to be on different rows.

This is the output I'm expecting from the sample data provided:

```
userIds     permissions
4,8     100,1600,500,501,502,400,401,1500,1501
5   100,1600,500,501,502,400,401,1500,1501
7   100,1600,500,501,502,400,401,1500,1501
```

**UPDATE**
I managed to get the desidered output in the following way:

```
-- Numbers table creation
DROP temporary TABLE IF EXISTS tally;

CREATE temporary TABLE tally
  (
     n INT NOT NULL auto_increment PRIMARY KEY
  );

INSERT INTO tally
            (n)
SELECT NULL
FROM   (SELECT 0 AS N
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 2
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 3
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 4
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 5
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 6
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 7
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 8
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 9) a,
       (SELECT 0 AS N
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 2
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 3
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 4
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 5
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 6
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 7
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 8
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 9) b;

-- Split users by comma from first table
DROP temporary TABLE IF EXISTS tmppermissions2;

CREATE temporary TABLE tmppermissions2
  (
     userid      VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
     permissions TEXT NOT NULL
  );

INSERT INTO tmppermissions2
SELECT userid,
       permissions
FROM   (SELECT Substring_index(Substring_index(t.userids, ',', tally.n), ',', -1
               )
                      userId,
               t.permissions
                      permissions
        FROM   tally
               INNER JOIN tmppermissions t
                       ON Char_length(t.userids) - Char_length(
                                                   REPLACE(t.userids, ',',
                                                   '')) >=
                          tally.n - 1
        ORDER  BY n) AS split;

-- Gets the users with the same permissions
DROP temporary TABLE IF EXISTS sharedprofiles;

CREATE temporary TABLE sharedprofiles
  (
     userids     VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
     permissions TEXT NOT NULL,
     profileid   INT(11)
  );

INSERT INTO sharedprofiles
SELECT Group_concat(userid),
       permissions,
       NULL
FROM   tmppermissions2
WHERE  userid NOT IN (SELECT split.userid
                      FROM   (SELECT Substring_index(Substring_index(r.userids,
                                                     ',',
                                                     t.n), ',', -1)
                                     userId
                              FROM   tally t
                                     INNER JOIN tmppermissions r
                                             ON Char_length(r.userids)
                                                - Char_length(
                                                REPLACE(r.userids, ',',
                                                '')) >=
                                                t.n - 1
                              WHERE  Position(',' IN r.userids) > 0
                              ORDER  BY n) AS split
                      WHERE  split.userid IN (SELECT *
                                              FROM   (SELECT Group_concat(userid
                                                             ORDER
                                                             BY userid ASC)
                                                             AS
                                                             users
                                                      FROM
                                             tmpcurrentresources2
                                                      GROUP  BY resourceid,
                                                                sectionid
                                                      ORDER  BY users) b
                                              WHERE  Position(',' IN b.users) =
                                                     0))
GROUP  BY permissions
ORDER  BY Group_concat(userid);

-- Gets the users with specific permissions
DROP temporary TABLE IF EXISTS singleprofiles;

CREATE temporary TABLE singleprofiles
  (
     userid      VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
     permissions TEXT NOT NULL,
     profileid   INT(11)
  );

INSERT INTO singleprofiles
SELECT userid,
       permissions,
       NULL
FROM   tmppermissions2
WHERE  userid IN (SELECT split.userid
                  FROM   (SELECT Substring_index(Substring_index(r.userids, ',',
                                                 t.n),
                                 ',', -1)
                                 userId
                          FROM   tally t
                                 INNER JOIN tmppermissions r
                                         ON Char_length(r.userids) -
                                            Char_length(
                                            REPLACE(r.userids, ',',
                                            '')) >=
                                            t.n - 1
                          WHERE  Position(',' IN r.userids) > 0
                          ORDER  BY n) AS split
                  WHERE  split.userid IN (SELECT *
                                          FROM   (SELECT Group_concat(userid
                                                         ORDER BY
                                                         userid ASC)
                                                         AS
                                                         users
                                                  FROM   tmpcurrentresources2
                                                  GROUP  BY resourceid,
                                                            sectionid
                                                  ORDER  BY users) b
                                          WHERE  Position(',' IN b.users) = 0))
ORDER  BY userid;

-- Merge the results
SELECT *
FROM  sharedprofiles
UNION
SELECT *
FROM  singleprofiles;
```

I'm wondering if there is a more concise way to accomplish the same result.

Comment: how this is related  to mysql ????  there is not query

Comment: @scaisEdge I added all the queries

Comment: There is, but I have a feeling you're not going to like it.

Comment: @Strawberry enlighten me, please

Answer (score 0):

The solution (as I suspect you already know) is to normalise your schema.

So instead of...

```
userIds     permissions
4,5         100,1600,500
```

...you might have

```
userIds     permissions
      4             100
      4            1600
      4             500
      5             100
      5            1600
      5             500
```